# Stacked hypothesis in ebproof

Tags: logic, ebproof

I am trying to write a proof tree using the ebproof package.  I have a long list of predicates most of which are short but one is really long e.g.:

```
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
    \hypo{h_4}
    \infer5[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
```

Now due to the length of `h_3` I want to stack the hypothesis to render something like:

```
   h_0     h_1     h_2
h_3 : a long predicate  h_4 
---------------------------- Label
        conclusion
```

I have come up with two related solutions using an inner proof tree to stack the hypotheses but both have some slight weirdness.

First attempt:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \infer[no rule]3{
        \begin{prooftree}
            \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
            \hypo{h_4}
            \infer[simple]2[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This almost works but the first line ends up centered over the whole inner proof tree including the label e.g.:

```
        h_0     h_1     h_2
h_3 : a long predicate  h_4 
---------------------------- Label
        conclusion
```

Now I can correct this by making the inference in the inner proof tree empty and adding a infer1 to the outer tree.  This does better but inserts some weird excess vertical white space (likely do the empty infer):

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \infer[no rule]3{
        \begin{prooftree}
            \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
            \hypo{h_4}
            \infer2{}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
    \infer1[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

results in:

```
   h_0     h_1     h_2
h_3 : a long predicate  h_4 

---------------------------- Label
        conclusion
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? If not is there a robust way to fix either method?

Full working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

% overfull hbox 
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
    \hypo{h_4}
    \infer5[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

% weird alingment
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \infer[no rule]3{
        \begin{prooftree}
            \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
            \hypo{h_4}
            \infer[simple]2[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

% excess vertical space
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \infer[no rule]3{
        \begin{prooftree}
            \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
            \hypo{h_4}
            \infer2{}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
    \infer1[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the solution.  It is possible to control vertical space around the inference line with the option `rule margin`.  By setting it to 0 I can eliminate the excess whitespace in my second solution:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{h_0}
    \hypo{h_1}
    \hypo{h_2}
    \infer[no rule]3{
        \begin{prooftree}[rule margin=0ex]
            \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
            \hypo{h_4}
            \infer2{}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
    \infer1[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

edit:

A generalization of this is

```
% Usage:
%   #1 : Number of \hypo in line 1 
%   #2 : line 1, it probably will do weird things if its not just a series of \hypo 
%   #3 : Number of \hypo in line 2
%   #4 : line 2, same note as above
\newcommand{\stackedhypos}[4]{%
    \hypo{
        \begin{prooftree}
            #2 % line 1
            \infer[no rule]#1{ 
                \begin{prooftree}[rule margin=0ex]
                    #4 % line 2
                    \infer[no rule]#3{}
                \end{prooftree}
            }
        \end{prooftree}
    }
}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
    \stackedhypos3{
        \hypo{h_0}
        \hypo{h_1}
        \hypo{h_2}
    }2{
        \hypo{h_3 : \textit{a long predicate}}
        \hypo{h_4}
    }
    \infer1[label]{\textit{conclusion}}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Putting line `#2 % line 1` inside a `prooftree` eliminates a bug when the top line is longer than the bottom.  The more direct generalization e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\stackedhypos}[4]{%
    #2 % line 1
    \infer[no rule]#1{ 
        \begin{prooftree}[rule margin=0ex]
            #4 % line 2
            \infer[no rule]#3{}
        \end{prooftree}
    }
}
```

Would render like this (when the lines are swapped):

```
  h_3 : a long predicate  h_4
     h_0     h_1     h_2 
     ------------------- Label
        conclusion
```

instead of like

```
  h_3 : a long predicate  h_4
     h_0     h_1     h_2 
  --------------------------- Label
        conclusion
```